# How to drop the database in SQL Server using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sql-drop

Dear I am using SQL Server 2008.

In my windows application there combo box having the list of all the databases.

I want to delete the database that's selected in combobox.

But when I run my query the following exception happens:

> *Cannot drop database "dm12" because it is currently in use*

Here is the code

```
 USE dm12
 GO
 DROP DATABASE dm12
 GO
```

Comment: Just a thought... tried removing `USE dm12 GO`?

Comment: why do you need to delete databases like this? What could possibly go wrong!

Comment: i have removed this but not working

Comment: you can not drop a database to which you are connected.

Comment: actually dear my all databases names bind to combo box so that's why the database is in use and sql server is not allowing to delete the database that's in use

Comment: Mitch Wheat! actually i made a designer for sql server.i can delete delete , update , check the data in tables views and doing many thing more

Comment: Ravindra Gullapalli! i have the closed the connection after selecting the names of databases.then why it's being happed

Answer (score 2):

If you want to drop the database use `master` database first and then drop the database.

Replace

```
USE dm12
```

With

```
USE Master;
```

Make sure you don't have any query tab open with the same database connection in SQL Server Management Studio.

And if you still get the same exception, then just close SQL Server Management Studio completely. Open it again and connect as normal

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough permission, the following code almost can guarantee you can drop database successfully. But why dropping database directly from application layer, how you control risk someone accidently delete database....

The alter database to single user and roll back immediately will cause all incomplete transactions to be rolled back and any other connections to the dm12 database to be immediately disconnected.

```
    USE master;
    GO
    ALTER DATABASE dm12
    SET SINGLE_USER
    WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    GO
    DROP DATABASE dm12;
    GO
```

Comment: dear i run this code but following error is occured

Msg 5011, Level 14, State 5, Line 1
User does not have permission to alter database 'DM13', the database does not exist, or the database is not in a state that allows access checks.
Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
Msg 3701, Level 11, State 1, Line 1
Cannot drop the database 'DM13', because it does not exist or you do not have permission

Comment: Please just follow the error message to investigate, like investigate if you have enough permission or if the database name you gave is correct. This script worked on my test server. If you still face issue, share more information, I'd like to help you.